# find the nearest 'n' neighbour in clustering algorithm of mahout

Tags: apache, cluster-analysis, mahout, nearest-neighbor

When I am running the apache mahout clustering examples of DisplayDirichlet.java, DisplayClustering.java or etc. the output is in graphical format.

1. How do I find the nearest neighbor containing 'n' number of items from a given item?
2. How do I know which are the items (by their item_id) falling in a cluster?